# Laravel blade table to AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have users with many receipts and partners. I need one table like this.

```
ID | Receipt Number | Username | Receipt Date | Partner name| Partner Phone |  Operations
```

Here is my controller. User has relationship with **receipts** and **partners** they returns result with i need.

```
 public function index()
{

    $user = Auth::id();
     $datas = Operation::with('user','receipt', 'partner')->where('user_id', $user)->get();
    return view('operations.index', compact('datas'));

}
```

Here is view

```
<table class="datatables-basic table" id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Partner</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Amallar</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $idx => $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$idx+1}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->receipt->number}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->user->username}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->receipt->date}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->partner->username}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->partner->phone}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-flat-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    Edit
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-flat-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-view"></i>
                    View
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-flat-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is `{{$data->receipt->number}}`, `{{$data->receipt->date}}`, `{{$data->partner->username}}` says "Property [date] does not exist on this collection".

And second problem how to convert this table to AJAX?

Here is Operation table

```
id| user_id | parner_id | receipt_id | date | amount | price
```

Here is receipt table

```
id | date | type | user_id
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it show the correct value `{{$data->receipt->number}}` ?

Comment: No it says "Property [number] does not exist on this collection".

Comment: Not `date`.  I am asking you to `number`. May be date has an empty value. first check `dd($datas)` shows proper data that you want

Comment: Here is collection `dd($datas)` [photo](https://i.imgur.com/ooZqZSG.png)

Comment: @HayrullaMelibayev, You have one to many relationship? so for one user you will get multiple receipt and parner

Comment: @YasinPatel yes  I have one to many relationship, and I'm getting multiple receipts and partners. This is first problem with i can not solve, how to print correct receipt number and correct partner name.

Comment: @HayrullaMelibayev, So You need to use foreach loop to display multiple records

Comment: I agree with @YasinPatel. You have to use foreach loop. For ajax request you have to prepare your data as an array and return array data from index and implement in your table

Comment: @HayrullaMelibayev, I see your collection has `hasMany` relation. Now my question is do you need multiple receipt number or first receipt number, or last receipt number as well as `date, username, phone`?

Comment: @A.ANoman I want to get that `username` wich equals `user.id = operation.user_id`, that `phone` which equals `parner.id = operations.partner_id` .

Comment: @YasinPatel you was right I changed controller to get operations also.

Comment: You are fetching number from collection same goes with date. That's not the way {{ dd($data->receipt) }} that will provide collection for you. So to get first number do {{ dd($data->receipt->first()->number) }} or {{ dd($data->receipt[0]->number) }} or for all number {{ dd($data->receipt->pluck('number')->toArray()) }}